# I'm a neuroscientist, what book should I read to improve my maths?

Tags: education

I'm a neuroscientist, but I don't know much maths. I like to learn the functions, and what they mean exactly and how/when I should use them. I'm specifically interested in knowing what mathematical functions actually mean and what I'm supposed to understand from them.

I want to read a little bit of maths every day and gradually build my knowledge over a year or two, and continue like that for a few years. What book do you recommend me to read (or start with)?

**Edit:** As some users correctly pointed out I should set the spectrum. The things that we use most are: Algebra, integrals and derivatives, logarithms, and trigonometric functions.

Comment: IMO it depends on your background. Depending on the last maths course you took, there are different starting points.

Comment: From what I have seen and been exposed to Graph Theory (Discrete Math), Statistics, and Linear Algebra are the top 3. Differential Equations also makes appearances from time to time. However, it really depends on what you want to study in Neuroscience.

Comment: If you are asking what mathematics is most useful for neuroscience, this seems like a question that's best asked to another neuroscientist.

Answer (score 2):

There is even a [Journal of Mathematical Neuroscience](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/computational+science+%26+engineering/journal/13408). An important part in neuroscience seems to be discrete mathematics.
So I recommend books in discrete mathematics, e.g., see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10209/resources-books-for-discrete-mathematics). Of course, like learning any other language, one should follow a grammar, and learn the vocabulary. Here I recommend the usual classes in analysis, linear algebra and abstract algebra.

Answer (score 0):

You use the term maths (which pleases me), suggesting that perhaps you may be in, or be familiar with with the UK academic system?  The A-Level curriculum is a good place to look for the currently recommended texts.  I grew up with the [OCR MEI Pure Maths book C1/C2](https://www.amazon.co.uk/MEI-Pure-Mathematics-3rd-Structured/dp/0340813970) which would be a prudent place for you to begin.  The following book C3/C4 addresses calculus and other essential techniques.  There are a number of 'additional' books.  They are for things like optional modules and extra curricula study. Topics include statistics (definitely read this, it will change your perspective on things when you review conditional probability) and differential equations.

I think this is where you ought to begin, to get the fundamentals down.  Then you can proceed to something like [Krezsig Advanced Engineering mathematics](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Advanced-Engineering-Mathematics-Erwin-Kreyszig/dp/0471728977/ref=sr_1_4?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1499287194&sr=1-4&keywords=Advanced%20Engineering%20Mathematics) which addresses practical mathematics for those who are not pure mathematicians.

If my assumption is wrong, and you are not in the UK, find books equivalent to these. Just start with the syllabus of the local academic institute.

Answer (score 0):

*I'm a neuroscientist, what book should I read to improve my maths?*

Maybe you should try [**Mathematics for Neuroscientists**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123748828).

According to the introduction, it is not required "more than one year of Calculus". If you have never studied calculus, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322892/calculus-book-recommendations-for-complete-beginner) there are some suggestions.