# Discrete mathematics programing exercises

Tags: discrete-mathematics, reference-request

I am looking for books or lecture notes with programing exercises for the discrete mathematics course. Any suggestions?

The stress is on **programing** in this question.

One example of what I am looking for could be **Discrete Mathematics Using a Computer** by *John O’Donnell, Cordelia Hall and Rex Page*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resources/Books for Discrete Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10209/resources-books-for-discrete-mathematics)

Comment: I have checked out most of these books, but all of them take the classical pencil&paper approach to problems. I am looking for books with interesting programming exercises. Something like Discrete Mathematics Using a Computer by John O’Donnell, Cordelia Hall and Rex Page.

Comment: oops.  i read "mathematics programming".