# What are the best mathematics books (for a 16 year old) for self learning?

Tags: reference-request, self-learning

I am really interested in some mathematics books for self learning  .I enjoy maths a lot and I am planning in pursuing a career in CS. Unfortunately, the maths I study at school is at a low level so I always had to make sure I was learning outside of it by visiting different sites, reading different books in english and sometimes even learning on youtube. Now I am struggling with finding great books for self learning so I am requiring your help. Would love if the books were not too advanced, but included everything a 16 year old or someone who is going to study CS in 2 years should know. Thanks in advance

Comment: What courses have you taken thus far? Have you taken any Calculus yet?

Comment: take a look at the following post. My personal favorite is concrete mathematics from Knuth et al. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/448923/recommended-maths-book-for-beginner-to-study-in-computer-science

Comment: @Steven01123581321: The post to which you linked is actually an unacknowledged paraphrase of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207486/a-good-introductory-discrete-mathematics-book/207527#207527). I agree that discrete math would be a good choice, and if Mateo can handle Graham, Knuth, & Patashnik, it would be an excellent choice.

Comment: @RyanK I have taken some pre-calculus courses and have also learned a bit about limits and integrals.

Comment: @Steven01123581321 Thanks a lot for the recommandation.